# Azure Kinect Sensor SDK - C# wrapper for image capture missing "Buffer"?

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk, azurekinect

I was watching video for "Intro to Developing for Azure Kinect - BRK1001".
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HzeYb00eQRI
At the time was writing code and noticed that property `Buffer` is not available on `Microsoft.Azure.Sensor.Image` but is being referenced on the presentation. How can I use `Buffer` in my code?

I've installed SDK 1.2.0-alpha.10
Microsoft video is from 7th May 2019, so it's not that old.

1) Capture from video:
[image]

2) Capture from my VS 2017:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can no longer obtain the native buffer directly. It must accessed through the managed Memory accessor at `color.Memory`. I'm not a user of the presentation core, but it may be possible to pass that as is to WritePixels. If not, use `Memory.ToArray()` to obtain a "byte[]"

Answer (score 1):

The production version of [C# wrapper](https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/issues/608) was just released last week. We are about to publish the sample code that will resolve your problem, but this is what you are looking for for now:

private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int count = 0;

```
        while (running)
        {
            using (Image transformedDepth = new Image(ImageFormat.Depth16, colorWidth, colorHeight, colorWidth * sizeof(UInt16)))
            using (Capture capture = await Task.Run(() => { return this.kinect.GetCapture(); }))
            {
                count++;

                this.transform.DepthImageToColorCamera(capture, transformedDepth);

                this.bitmap.Lock();

                var color = capture.Color;
                var region = new Int32Rect(0, 0, color.WidthPixels, color.HeightPixels);

                unsafe
                {
                    using (var pin = color.Memory.Pin())
                    {
                        this.bitmap.WritePixels(region, (IntPtr)pin.Pointer, (int)color.Size, color.StrideBytes);
                    }

                    if (boundingBox != null)
                    {
                        int y = (boundingBox.Y + boundingBox.H / 2);
                        int x = (boundingBox.X + boundingBox.W / 2);

                        this.StatusText = "The person is:" + transformedDepth.GetPixel<ushort>(y, x) + "mm away";
                    }
                }

                this.bitmap.AddDirtyRect(region);
                this.bitmap.Unlock();

                if (count % 30 == 0)
                {
                    var stream = StreamFromBitmapSource(this.bitmap);
                    _ = computerVision.AnalyzeImageInStreamAsync(stream, MainWindow.features).ContinueWith((Task<ImageAnalysis> analysis) =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            foreach (var item in analysis.Result.Objects)
                            {
                                if (item.ObjectProperty == "person")
                                {
                                    this.boundingBox = item.Rectangle;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (System.Exception ex)
                        {
                            this.StatusText = ex.ToString();
                        }
                    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```